# The difference between accuracy of test(60%) and training(99.9%) data sets is huge indicating high variance

Tags: random-forest, data-science, decision-tree, cross-validation, variance

What should I do to to reduce variance.I checked for multicollinearity using VIF.VIF for all the parameters was less than 2.AIC and BIC are high.Adj R^2 is around 0.45 which is less.The condition number is also high.What should I do?
I am using decision trees and random forests to build the model.

Comment: As this question is not about programming, but rather model design and validation, it is best asked on [stats.SE].

Comment: Get better training data.